# Difference between elevation and z-index in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, css, material-ui, z-index

I was going through the documentation of material-ui. It's **documentation** says:

> Several Material-UI components utilize z-index, the CSS property that
>   helps control layout by providing a third axis to arrange content. We
>   utilize a default z-index scale in Material-UI that's been designed to
>   properly layer drawers, modals, snackbars, tooltips, and more.

*I want to make a component such that on button click, it pops on the top of another component and disappears after a task is finished.* 
**My question is should I use elevation property by wrapping up the popper component in a paper component or should I use z-index? What is the difference in the usage of elevation and zIndex in material-ui, as material-ui itself uses zIndex for the styling on third axis?**

Comment: zIndex controls which element has precedence on the top level - so yes use this for your scenario. Elevation is aesthetic as it will apply some shadow to make some element appear to be "floating" or "elevated".

Comment: @ehutchllew Since this is answering the question and not just asking for clarification, please add it as an answer rather than as a comment so that it can more easily be found by future users with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ehutchllew indicated in the comments, elevation is unrelated to z-index and gives the Paper a raised look via shadowing. z-index controls which element is on top when positioned elements overlap.

Here is an example demonstrating both:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const styles = {
  root: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10
  }
};
function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Paper elevation={0} classes={classes}>
        Elevation 0
      </Paper>
      <Paper classes={classes}>Default Elevation (2)</Paper>
      <Paper elevation={4} classes={classes}>
        Elevation 4
      </Paper>
      <Paper elevation={8} classes={classes}>
        Elevation 8
      </Paper>
      <Paper elevation={16} classes={classes}>
        Elevation 16
      </Paper>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <div
          style={{
            height: 20,
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            position: "relative",
            top: 0,
            zIndex: 2
          }}
        >
          zIndex - I have a middle zIndex value
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            height: 20,
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            position: "relative",
            top: -10,
            zIndex: 3
          }}
        >
          zIndex - I have the highest
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
            position: "relative",
            top: -50,
            zIndex: 1
          }}
        >
          zIndex - I have the lowest
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit elevation]

Comment: Great Explanation...This is what I was exactly looking for.